# How do I learn when to apply which statistical distributions?

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, references, application

I am learning Bayesian modeling and having trouble keeping straight when it is most appropriate to apply the various statistical distributions beyond the basic ones like the beta, binomial, and Gaussian.

Are there resources out there that provide overviews of the practical applications of various distributions, in particular less commonly used ones? I am aware of the 2011 by Catherine Forbes et al., which does a great job of presenting the mathematical properties of the various statistical distribution, but I want something that helps me with application. I would appreciate any references to books, articles, or websites.

Comment: The first step is to identify the support for the random variable you are trying to model.

Comment: "Supposed to" suggests that there's some authority telling you what models you may choose. That's not how it works. Certainly there are considerations that would make some models implausible (the support jaradiemi mentioned being an important one) but there are a variety of things a statistician might take into account when considering a model, and may well choose a model that they can know with certainty must not be correct. There won't generally be a "should" about it -- almost every model you consider will be wrong (*how wrong does it have to be to not be useful?*)

Comment: It might be helpful if you are able to clarify the particular kind of guidance you seek

Comment: Thank you, @Glen_b. I edited my question to remove the deontic modal. I also made it more explicit that I am looking for literature that I can read to develop a feel for the application of the various statistical distributions.

Comment: It seems you are asking the question 'How to become a good statistician?'. I (for myself) consider myself to be a bad statistician because I have never really tackeled a real world problem by modelling it explicitly with densities (except for some exotic bayesian approaches) but I pretty much guess that you need to gather experience and the more experience you gather, the more 'good' you will be. So my advice would be: start your private collection of densities that you understood (because you applied them once) and solve as many real world problems as you can find and ask here about them :-)

Comment: You still have a *should be* there, and "is most appropriate to" isn't much better (you seem to be seeking someone else to make the decisions about modeling tradeoffs for you -- to tell you what is appropriate for you when we don't know your circumstances nor preferences). There are many common choices (distributions often used for interevent times, for survival times, for counts, for sizes of various physical things, for incomes, for stock returns, for choices among categories, for continuous proportions and so on), but that would seem to be a "big list" question.

Comment: @Glen_b No, I'm not looking for someone else to make decisions for me. It is clear that statisticians have intuitions about which probability distributions to use when. What I am trying to do is to cultivate those intuitions for myself and am looking for resources with which I can achieve that goal.

Comment: @FabianWerner No, I'm not asking such a general open-ended question. I'm looking for resources on the practical application of statistical distributions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any general answer, besides telling you to look into the literature about the kind of data you are analyzing. I am aware at least of some cases where the question about the underlying distribution is still subject to debate, so for these cases, one cannot know what distribution to pick.

For example, for response times there is [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b255/6774493ebf624a091eaf71ee22885ef89536.pdf), which discusses that they may be described by either log-normal, inverse-normal (Wald), ex-Gaussian, or Weibull distribution. Also, it mentions that the most common approach is to use an ex-Gaussian distribution. On the other hand, an ex-Gaussian is clearly wrong, because it has some support in the negative values, which cannot be the case for response times, which always must be positive.

Thus, this question can be very hard to answer. The usual approach I take is, that I try not to be to wrong ("all models are wrong") and use something that has been debated in the literature and gives me the properties I want.

For example, for RTs I usually use a log-normal, because log transformations are most common on RTs in other fields as well and also I can then use the mode or the mean of the log-normal as a hyperparameter in a hierarchical model (i.e. I can estimate mean and sd separately). While an ex-Gaussian would probably be better given the literature, I would have more parameters and I cannot easily just estimate the mean independently of other parameters (mean is $\mu+\nu$, so I have to pick one of those to get the other). If I had some intuition about the meaning of $\mu$ and $\nu$ in the ex-Gaussian for some experiments, I would probably use that one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate all the points that you made. As revealed also by the comments above, I think there has been a persistent misunderstanding in what I am asking for. I am not asking for anyone to layout the practical applications of each distribution (that would of course be difficult to do). I am asking for guidance in terms of resources.

Comment: @Namenlos: In that case, the main resources probably come from the field you are working in. E.g., for response times the paper I linked is probably the best resource. For other kinds of data, you should also look at the appropriate literature in that field most likely. I don't think anybody has compiled a resource or even a list of resources spanning multiple fields, after all, why should the distributions for e.g. neutrino impacts be in the same resource as human response times. For priors, I also use this resource a lot: https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/wiki/Prior-Choice-Recommendations

Comment: Thank you for the link! That's helpful. I'm working in a field where Bayesian inference (and statistically modeling in general) is underdeveloped, so it lacks the literature in other fields.

Comment: I agree, it may be a problem if Bayesian inference is underdeveloped in your field. However, the literature that can help you pick the distribution does not have to be about Bayesian inference necessarily. The paper I linked above is not about Bayesian methods, but still gives some intuition about the distribution. As such other Literature analysing the distributions or even about (non-Bayesian) parameter estimation in your field may give you ideas what to use in your Bayesian models.